# What reasoning processes underlie the Logima Strictica 36 and Logicaus Strictimanus 24?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, intelligence, artificial-intelligence

I am conducting research in creating an AI with high IQ.
I am interested in the tests [Logima Strictica 36 Test](http://news.generiq.net/LS36/ls36test.html) and [Logicaus Strictimanus 24](http://news.generiq.net/LS24/ls24test.html). [Further links are here](http://news.generiq.net/)

- What is the logic of these test items?
- What reasoning processes underly these test items?

Comment: `my research in creating an AI with high IQ` more focused questions about this area might be on topic, but as it stands this is way too wide, would fill *several* textbooks, and would probably win whoever answered the Nobel Prize.

Comment: It is not the role of this site to provide answers to public IQ tests, especially where such resources could serve to reduce the public value of such tests. I've given the question a tweak to focus on the psychological question. I.e., what reasoning processes underlie the test?